# Form dynamic JSON objects in Android

Tags: android, json

I am trying to form the JSON data attached here with. How to form it, please let me know:

[image: create this JSON]

Comment: hi, any ideas on this issue.

Comment: have you tried ?? post code

Comment: I haven't tried yet. But I think I can create a list and insert the count like 0, 1, 2 etc along with it's data and create objects accordingly.